Stars that have fairly high gravitational redshift and calculation of their surface temperature by Planck emition spectra?
How high can the ratio between gravitational redshift and planck emition spectra be depending on the mass of the star so by how much this gravitational redshift could elongate the Planck spectra of the radiation emitted by the star surface?

What does "ratio between gravitational redshift and Planck emission spectra" mean? The former is a dimensionless number, while the latter is characterized by a dimensionful temperature or energy. Also, what do you mean by "elongate the Planck spectra"? Note that gravitational redshift simply shifts the emission spectrum to a different energy/temperature, although if there is a range of redshifts (e.g. associated with different parts of the star), that could distort it.

The gravitational redshift inferred by a distant observer, when measuring the spectrum of radiation from the surface of a star of mass $M$ and radius $R$ is given by
$$\frac{\lambda}{\lambda_0} = \left(1 - \frac{2GM}{Rc^2}\right)^{-1/2}\ , $$
where $\lambda_0$ is the wavelength of light measured by an observer at the surface of the star where it is emitted and $\lambda$ is the wavelength that light appears to have when measured by a distant observer. You can see that $\lambda > \lambda_0$ by a factor that depends on the "compactness" of the star $M/R$.
If we rewrite $2GM/c^2$ as the Schwarzschild radius $R_s$ (appropriate, since the formula above implicitly assumes that the Schwarzschild metric can be used outside a spherically symmetric, non-spinning object), then the redshift factor becomes dependent on the dimensionless ratio $R_s/R$.
There is a maximum value that this ratio can take, that is smaller than 1, beyond which no stable stellar configuration is possible. This maximum ratio is 8/9 if the star is supported by some incompressible fluid. For more realistic equations of state supporting a neutron star, the maximum is likely to be lower, around 0.7. This means that the largest possible gravitational redshift will be a factor of about 1.8.
It is possible to increase this by allowing the star to spin extremely quickly, but even for the fastest spinning observer pulsars don't spin fast enough to change the above result significantly.
Since the surface effective temperature, inferred from Wien's law, is inversely proportional to wavelength, then the object appears cooler by a factor no smaller than 1/1.8.

So for regular stars, not dead remnants, you can estimate this by setting the potential energy at the star's surface equal to the kinetic energy of an in-falling mass:
$$ m\frac{GM} R = \frac 1 2 m v^2 $$
And from there, just compute the standard SR Lorentz factor:
$$ \gamma = \frac 1 {\sqrt{1 - 2\frac{GM} {Rc^2}}}$$
And then apply that as an appropriate scaling factor.
For the Sun, you get:
$$ \gamma = 1.000002 $$
or a shift of "two parts in a million".
At a typical visible wavelength of 500 nm, that is 0.01 angstrom (which is the unit a search of solar spectrometer resolution turns up, e.g https://bass2000.obspm.fr/solar_spect.php), and that site claims 0.002 angstrom. So it's easily observable (Note: I ignored the fact that we observe the Sun from the Earth, not infinity, but that is a 1/2 percent correction to the energy, which is a negligible change to $\gamma$).
Now if I pick a blue supergiant like Rigel, it has $M=23M_{solar}$ and $R=74R_{solar}$, so the effect is even less, and the spectroscopy on some thing that dim vs. the Sun is not going to be as accurate.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigel says the "Apparent Visual Magnitude" is 6.67, which means it's wrong, or I don't know what that term means, so I won't tell you how much brighter the Sun is, but it's roughly:
$$ (100)^{\frac{26} 5} \approx 25\times 10^9 $$
